# HTML Form Issue on IE

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

I have an HTML form which uses an image as a submit button. The problem I have is the value="Submit" is showing up as text over the submit image button on IE7 & IE8. can anyone tell how to prevent this? Thanks!

```
<div>
 <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the entire form?  What's a "submit image button"?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably change

```
 value="Submit"
```

to

```
 value="&nbsp;"
```

Or

It looks like you may need to change it to input type="image" instead of input type="submit"

Or

Possibly the submit button can be an Anchor or a Div with an onclick event handler.